# Extract from formatted string using Java

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

I have strings of the following formats:

- [(xx)(KEY1)some text]
- Some text [(yy)(KEY1)some text]
- Some text [(qq)(KEY1)some text] More text here [(zz)(KEY2)some text] etc.

Basically the form **[(xx)(KEYX)some text]** appears once or multiple times in a string mingled with other characters.

In the above format, the key is *KEYX* and the value is *some text*.

I would like to extract all the key value pairs from any string containing any number of such formats.

I tried using straight parsing using substring etc., but that does not seem a clean solution. Is it possible to do it better using regex or any other technique that Java provides?

Comment: Is KEYX always 4 character? Does it always start with the third character?

Comment: KEYX is a variable string. It can take any string value. But it is always enclosed within (). It is always the third character. The prefix values (xx) or (yy) are exactly like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regex and matcher to find your key and value:

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
     {
         String test = "[(xx)(KEYX)some text]";
         Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(KEY.*\\)");

         Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
         matcher.find();
         String s = matcher.group(0);
         String s1 = test.substring(matcher.end(), test.length() - 1);
         System.out.println("" + s + "   " + s1);

     }
```

Output of this would be:

```
(KEYX)   some text
```

If you change string to `"[(xx)(KEYXYYYYYY)some text]"` then it would be:

```
(KEYXYYYYYY)   some text
```

If you don't want parenthesis around key:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
     String test = "[(xx)(KEYXYYYYYY)some text]";
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\()KEY.*(?=\\))");

     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
     matcher.find();
     String s = matcher.group(0);
     String s1 = test.substring(matcher.end() + 1, test.length() - 1);
     System.out.println("" + s + "   " + s1);

 }
```

Output would be:

```
KEYXYYYYYY   some text
```

**************************************************************UPDATE**********************************************************
Match anything for key not just KEY:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
     String test = "[(xx)(time.zone1)some text]";
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\()[^xy].*(?=\\))");

     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
     matcher.find();
     String s = matcher.group(0);
     String s1 = test.substring(matcher.end() + 1, test.length() - 1);
     System.out.println("" + s + "   " + s1);

 }
```

This will output:

```
time.zone1   some text
```

**********************************************************UPDATE**********************************************

Multiple matches in same String:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
     String test = "[(xx)(time1.zone1)some text1]blahblahblah[(xx)(time2.zone2)some text2]";
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\()[^xy].*?]");

     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
     while(matcher.find())
     {
         String s = matcher.group(0);
         String s1 = s.substring((s.indexOf(")") + 1), (s.length() - 1));
         s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(")"));
         System.out.println("" + s + "   " + s1);
     }

 }
```

This will output:

```
time1.zone1   some text1
time2.zone2   some text2
```

Comment: Thank you brso5. One thing though. The key does not start with the string "KEY". It can be anything. For example, the following are all valid keys: time.zone1; url.someval; some.key.val etc

Comment: @naspras Hey man I just updated it so you will match any key not just something that starts with KEY...check out the update section

Comment: I was away for last couple of days. This solutions is helpful for what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: It does not work if I have an input as this: some text [(XX)(A.KEY)some_text] write blah blah [(XX)(OTHER.VAL)some_more_text] hi hello. The simple intention is finding the keys (A.KEY,  OTHER.VAL) following every occurrence of (XX).

Comment: So you mean all in one string?  You should use a loop with the matcher...I can post code for that.

Comment: I would appreciate that. Thanks!

Comment: @naspras just updated the post check out the newest code I had to change the regex a little this should work for you...

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work as well :). Thanks for the quick help. +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you could rely on the `KEY` starting at the fourth character and then find the next ")" like

```
String str = "(xx)(KEY1)some text";
int open = str.indexOf("(", 4);
int pos = str.indexOf(")", 4);
str = str.substring(open + 1, pos);
System.out.println(str);
```

Output is

```
KEY1
```